# create project from maven2 repository

Tags: maven-2, repository, pom.xml

I want to create a maven2 project from artifacts in maven2 repository (POM and sources). Of course,I can create the directory structure, copy POM file and extract the sources manually. But I wonder if I can automate this task with maven.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [dependency:unpack-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) can help you? Note, there are parameters such as *classifier*, *copyPom*, *outputDirectory*, *type*, etc that can be used to configure the content of the output.

Comment: This plugin deals with the dependencies of already existing project, and I need to create a new project tree (like the archetype plugin does), but fill this tree with data from an existing repository project.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Maven archetype plugin](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/) can serve your need?  It allows you to create an archetype, which can then be used to create a project.

Comment: I do not want to create a brand new project, I want to tell maven, using the artifact Id of an existing project, download the project's pom.xml and sources, then create project tree and unpack sources in the tree.